# How to get the string value of all selected checkboxes in Java netbeans

Tags: java

```
jButton1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent Arg0){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, getSelected());
             }
    });

 public String getSelected() {
    //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    String subs ="";

    for (Component c:getComponents()){
        if(c instanceof JCheckBox)
            if(((JCheckBox)c).isSelected())
                subs +=((JCheckBox)c).getText()+",";
    }
     return subs;
}
```

here is my code it shows nothing on output, Ive tried some other methods like arraylist and list but i dont get it I ends up too many errors